# How to read from text files and sorted the lines based on a particular category and print it on python shell

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

How can I read the text file and print the lines on my python shell, but the lines have to be sorted with the Part ID? How can I sort these lines based on the Part ID? (Ex: ABS01, ABS01, BBS02, BWBS03,  ES04, TS05)

And also how can I detect which (parts) quantity left in the warehouse is less than 10 so that I can print those with less than the quantity of 10?

Thank you for your help ~

The contents in my text file:
Section: AS Part ID: ABS01  Order from warehouse to aircond section: 500    Piston quantity left in the warehouse: 1000
Section: BS Part ID: BBS02  Order from warehouse to brake section: 600  brakepads quantity left in the warehouse: 1000
Section: ES Part ID: ES04   Order from warehouse to engine section: 100 brakepads quantity left in the warehouse: 1000
Section: BWS    Part ID: BWBS03 Order from warehouse to bodywork section: 700   Door quantity left in the warehouse: 1000
Section: TS Part ID: TS05   Order from warehouse to tyre section: 300   Door quantity left in the warehouse: 1000
Section: AS Part ID: ABS01  Order from warehouse to aircond section: 300    Piston quantity left in the warehouse: 700

```
try:
    fHand = open("AssemblySecDetails.txt")
    partsDetails = fHand.read()
    print(partsDetails)
    fHand.close()
except:
    print("File Not Found")
    exit()
```

Comment: If `f` is the file descriptor you can read the lines with `lines = f.readlines()`. Now we sort the list according to the fifth word (the part id): `lines.sort(key=lambda line: line.split()[4])`. Now print it: `print(''.join(lines))`. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

According to your provided code (which basically does nothing), have a look at:

- [`readlines`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) how to read lines from file
- [regular expressions module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), a powerful tool for string manipulation
- [sorting in python](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html)

For your case and `sample.txt`

```
Section: AS Part ID: ABS01 Order from warehouse to aircond section: 500 Piston quantity left in the warehouse: 1000
Section: BS Part ID: BBS02 Order from warehouse to brake section: 600 brakepads quantity left in the warehouse: 1000
Section: ES Part ID: ES04 Order from warehouse to engine section: 100 brakepads quantity left in the warehouse: 1000
Section: BWS Part ID: BWBS03 Order from warehouse to bodywork section: 700 Door quantity left in the warehouse: 1000
Section: TS Part ID: TS05 Order from warehouse to tyre section: 300 Door quantity left in the warehouse: 1000
Section: AS Part ID: ABS01 Order from warehouse to aircond section: 300 Piston quantity left in the warehouse: 700
```

this code works:

```py
import re
with open("sample.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
ids = [re.search("Part ID: (\w+)",line).group(1) for line in lines]
aux = zip(ids,lines)
aux2 = sorted(aux)
for id,line in aux2:
    print(line,end="")
```

- first, `ids` are extracted using `re.search` and `re` groups
- then, `zip(ids,lines)` auxiliary value is created, producing something like `[(id1,line1),(id2,line2),...]`
- it is then `sorted`, which in case of tuples uses by default the first item (`id`) for the sort
- finally print `line` from the result. Line contains newline charanter at the end, so `print(...end="")` is used

A oneliner:

```py
with open("sample.txt") as f:print("".join(sorted(f,key=lambda l:re.search("Part ID: (\w+)",l).group(1))),end="")
```

#### Edit to OP edit:

To filter the lines according to a condition is as easy as

```py
filteredLines = [line for line in lines if condition(line)]
```

using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) where `condition` is a function returning `True`/`False`, e.g.

```py
def condition(line):
    quantity = re.search("quantity left in the warehouse: (\d+)",line).group(1)
    quantity = int(quantity)
    return quantity < 10
```

Again, you can do it without `re`, but I see no point in it.. If you want to learn python, learn python with its power

Comment: Hi, thank you for your time and I really appreciate your solution for my schoolwork, but it seems like the requirement of my schoolwork only allows me to use basic python commands (meaning no import of any module) as it is testing my ability to solve a problem with the basics of python - -. Is it possible to translate your current solution to a more basic level of python code? Thanks for your response once again (I am starting out as a beginner in python, hope you don't mind my dumbness ><)

Comment: Next time, make the requirements clear in the OP. `re` is a part of python standard library. So of course it is possible without `re`, but why making it more difficult, less readable etc.? if you really want to go this way, have a look at [`str.partition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) and [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and [`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) methods

Comment: Alright, thank you for your feedback, I will do better next time ><. I have actually updated my question by adding one more question. Do you mind having a look at it?

Comment: I will edited my answer, but it would be better to ask a new question IMO..

Comment: def condition(parts):
    fHand = open("AssemblySecDetails.txt", 'r')
    partsDetails = fHand.readlines()
    filteredLines = [parts for parts in partsDetails if condition(parts)]
    quantity = re.search("quantity left in the warehouse: (\d+)", parts).group(1)
    quantity = int(quatity)
    return quantity < 10
condition(parts)

Hi, I have tried out the code that you provided, I wonder what argument I should pass to the parts in condition(parts) to call the function?

Comment: line form the file is the parameter of `condition`, so `fHand = open("AssemblySecDetails.txt", 'r')` `partsDetails = fHand.readlines()` `def condition(part): ... ` `filteredLines = [parts for parts in partsDetails if condition(parts)]`

Comment: Really, consider to ask a new question if you have a new question

Comment: Alright, I have added a new question. 

https://stackoverflow.com/q/63848619/13403256